# Emulate a Relational Database with XML

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, datasource

I'm developing a Windows Phone app.

I want to make a prototype with some sample data that I have in a SQLite database.

I don't know if it is the best approach to make a single XML file with all tables inside. Or, maybe, I can use a XML file foreach table.

What do you think? What do you recommend me?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use SQLite directly on the device? Rudi Grobler has a useful post about using [SQLite on WP7](http://www.rudigrobler.net/blog/sqlite-on-wp7)

Comment: Because it is a prototype. I'm only need to know that if I can use a single XML file to store all tables or I need a XML file for each table.

Comment: Fair enough. It just seems to be the path of least resistance to use the existing SQLite database :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is only my suggestion. Create a DataSet at runtime and add DataTables inside. You can save the DataSet as XML and vice versa. Hope you consider it will help. Thank you!